# AWS SSM Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I want to access some parameter values from the Parameter Store in AWS Systems Manager in an AWS Lambda function written in Java.

Can someone kindly provide me with a suitable example as how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameters.html) for Amazon as well as the [Java client docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html). `GetParametersRequest` is probably what you want.

Comment: I used the API Documentation but still I was not able to successfully fetch the Parameter Value.